# Image breaking in a wordpress custom site - php file and problems with root path

Tags: php, wordpress, image, wordpress-theming, footer

I am having trouble with a very simple footer - for some reason. While trying to load an Instagram icon in a footer, while editing a custom WordPress theme, everything seems okay and the image is linking right, but breaking. what could be the possible reasons?

This is what I tried, I would expect to work just fine (used svg. png...:

```
?>
<footer id="colophon" class="site-footer">
    <div class="site-info">
        <div class="footer-copyright">
            &copy; Mother tongues collective 2023. All rights reserved.
        </div>
        <div class="footer-socials">
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/mother.tongues_/" target="_blank">
                <!-- #instagram icon -->
                <img src="<?php bloginfo('template-url'); ?>/assets/instagram-icon.png">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div><!-- .site-info -->

    <?php wp_footer(); ?>
</footer><!-- #colophon -->



</body>
</html>
```

Many thanks in advance for any help[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1AflE.png)

Answer (score 1):

`template-url` is an invalid argument for [`bloginfo()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/bloginfo/) – you may have meant `template_url` or `template_directory`:

```php
 <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/assets/instagram-icon.png">
```